# Differential equation $y' = (2y^2 + x)/(3y^2 + 5)$ (Apostol, section 8.28, ex. 30)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

**Problem**

This is from Apostol's Calculus book, section 8.28, exercise 30.

> Let $y = f(x)$ be that solution of the differential equation
>
> $$y' = \dfrac{2y^2 + x}{3y^2 + 5}$$
>
> which satisfies the initial condition $f(0) = 0$.
>
> **(a)** The differential equation shows that $f'(0) = 0$. Discuss whether $f$ has a relative maximum or minimum or neither at 0.
>
> **(b)** Notice that $f'(x) \geq 0$ for each $x \geq 0$ and that $f'(x) \geq \frac{2}{3}$ for each $x \geq \frac{10}{3}$. Exhibit two positive numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x) > ax - b$ for each $x \geq \frac{10}{3}$.
>
> **(c)** Show that $x/y^2 \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$.
>
> **(d)** Show that $y/x$ tends to a finite limit as $x \to +\infty$ and determine this limit.

**Solution attempt**

Please, I would like to ask for verification of my attempt below.

**(a)** The second derivative is given by:

$$y'' = \dfrac{(3y^2 + 5)(4yy' + 1) - 6yy'(2y^2 + x)}{(3y^2 + 5)^2}$$

At zero, the value is:

$$f''(0) = \dfrac{5}{(5)^2} = \dfrac{1}{5}$$

Since this value is positive, we can conclude that the concavity of $f$ at 0 is up, so $f$ has a relative minimum at 0.

**(b)** Since $f'(x) \geq \frac{2}{3}$ for each $x \geq \frac{10}{3}$, in order to have the line $ax - b$ below $f(x)$, we can choose $a = \frac{2}{3}$. Also, we can choose $b$ such that $ax - b = 0$ at $x = \frac{10}{3}$ (since $f(x) \geq 0$ there). This gives:

$$\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{10}{3} - b = 0 \implies b = \frac{20}{9}$$

So, the numbers are $a = \frac{2}{3}$ and $b = \frac{20}{9}$.

**(c)** In item (b), we found that:

$$y > \frac{2}{3}x - \frac{20}{9}$$

for $x \geq \frac{10}{3}$. This implies:

$$\frac{3}{2} y + \frac{10}{3} > x$$

for $x \geq \frac{10}{3}$. Dividing both sides by $y^2$, this becomes:

$$\dfrac{3}{2y} + \dfrac{10}{3y^2} > \dfrac{x}{y^2}$$

Also, we know that $x/y^2 \geq 0$, so we have:

$$\dfrac{3}{2y} + \dfrac{10}{3y^2} > x/y^2 \geq 0$$

Since we know that $y > \frac{2}{3}x - \frac{20}{9}$, we have that $y \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$, so the left-hand side of the left-hand inequality above tends to zero as $x \to \infty$:

$$\dfrac{3}{2y} + \dfrac{10}{3y^2} \to 0\text{ as }x \to \infty$$

Therefore, by the squeeze theorem, it follows that $x/y^2 \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$.

**(d)** From item (c), we know that $x/y^2 \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$. So:

$$\begin{aligned}
    \lim_{x \to +\infty} y' &= \lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{2y^2 + x}{3y^2 + 5} \\
    &= \lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{2 + x/y^2}{3 + 5/y^2} \\
    &= \dfrac{2 + 0}{3 + 0} \\
    &= \dfrac{2}{3}
\end{aligned}$$

So, as $x \to +\infty$, the function $y$ approaches a line of slope $\frac{2}{3}$. That is, $y$ approaches a line of the form $y=\frac{2}{3}x + C$, so $y/x \to \frac{2}{3}$ as $x \to +\infty$.

The argument in part (d) seems a bit informal; I'm not sure how to make it more rigorous.

Comment: You could invoke the theorem of l'Hopital for a limit $\frac\infty\infty$.

Comment: $\int_a^x y'(t)\,dt = y(x) - y(a)$. If $m \le y' \le M$, then $m(x-a) \le y(x) - y(a) \le M(x-a)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Coming back to this post after a long time, but I posted an answer to it with a new argument for part (d) based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Paul Sinclair's suggestion in the comments to the question, here is an attempt at a new argument for part (d).

We found that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y' = 2/3$. This means that, given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $N > 0$ such that, if $x > N$, then

$$\left|y' - \dfrac{2}{3}\right| < \epsilon$$

This implies

$$-\epsilon < y' - \dfrac{2}{3} < \epsilon \implies -\epsilon + \dfrac{2}{3} < y' < \epsilon + \dfrac{2}{3}$$

Integrating, we get:

$$\begin{aligned}
    &\int_0^x \left(-\epsilon + \dfrac{2}{3}\right) dz < \int_0^x y' dz < \int_0^x \left(\epsilon + \dfrac{2}{3}\right) dz \\
    \implies & \left(-\epsilon + \dfrac{2}{3}\right)x < y - y(0) < \left(\epsilon + \dfrac{2}{3}\right)x \\
    \implies & \left(-\epsilon + \dfrac{2}{3}\right)x < y < \left(\epsilon + \dfrac{2}{3}\right)x
\end{aligned}$$

Dividing by $x$ (since $x \neq 0$), we get:

$$\begin{aligned}
    &-\epsilon + \dfrac{2}{3} < \dfrac{y}{x} < \epsilon + \dfrac{2}{3} \\
    \implies & -\epsilon < \dfrac{y}{x} - \dfrac{2}{3} < \epsilon \\
    \implies & \left|\dfrac{y}{x} - \dfrac{2}{3}\right| < \epsilon
\end{aligned}$$

That is, we have shown that, given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $N > 0$ such that, if $x > N$, then $|y/x - 2/3| < \epsilon$. That is,

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{y}{x} = \dfrac{2}{3}$$

as required.

Comment: You only know that $-\epsilon + \frac 23 < y'(t) < \epsilon + \frac 23$ for $t > N$, but in your integration, you assume it is true on all of $[0,x]$. (FYI - it really bad form to use the same label $x$ for the upper limit of integration and for the dummy variable of the integration. These two variables cannot be the same, as the dummy variable has no definition outside the integration, while the limits must be defined outside. Using the same letter for two different things in the same context will cause confusion for both you and your audience.)

Comment: The results that are useful here are that a continuous function on a compact interval (closed and bounded) will have a maximum and minimum on that interval. In particular, it will be bounded. And because the limit as $x\to\infty$ converges, $y'$ is bounded on $[N, \infty)$ for some $N$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Edited to correct the dummy variable. And right, it was not valid to integrate from $0$ to $x$, so the remainder of this solution is not right. I could integrate from $N$ to $x$, but it wouldn't yield a very useful result. So, I'm not really seeing right now how to get, from here, to the result that $\lim_{x \to \infty} y/x = 2/3$.

Comment: I told you how to fix the issue in my second comment. You've already shown that $y'$ is bounded on $[N, \infty)$ for some $N$. What is left is showing it is also bounded on $[0,N]$. The rest of the your proof other than the bounds is okay. You just need to show that $y'$ is bounded above and below by some numbers $m$ and $M$.